# Limit PER user in rails query

Tags: ruby-on-rails

So I have a standard **users** table structure, with a primary id key and what so not and the following **persona** table:

```
 user_id | persona_id | time_inserted
 2              1             x
 2              2             x+1
 2              3             x+2
 1              1             x+3
 5              8             x+6
 5              9             x+1
```

What I'd like to do is retrieve the **LAST** inserted row and limit to **ONE** per user id. So, in that query, the result I want would be:

[2, 3] because the last inserted for 2 was persona_id 3 (x+2), [1, 1], and [5,8] because the last inserted for 5 was persona_id 8 (x+6)

This is my query:

```
to_return = Persona.select(to_get).where(to_condition)
```

This works, but retrieves them all. How can I restrict the query as asked? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work:

```
to_return = Persona.select(to_get).where(to_condition).group('user_id').having('time_inserted = MAX(time_inserted)')
```

#### Update

You can't select a column if you don't put that in the `group` clause. 
As you want to group by only `user_id`, one possible solution is, select the `user_id` s first with the maximum `time_inserted` like this:

```
users_ids_relation = Persona.select('user_id').group('user_id').having('time_inserted = MAX(time_inserted)')
```

Then, join it with the `personas` table based on the condition and then select the required columns:

```
users_ids_relation.joins('personas').where(to_condition).select(to_get)
```

It will give you the expected result.

Comment: but  will this return the last one for EACH id? Like
{[2,3],[1,1],[5,8]} ?

Comment: It should give that now. Let me know if not.
`to_return = Persona.select(to_get).where(to_condition).group('user_id').having('time_inserted = MAX(time_inserted)')
`

Comment: @Fane did you try it? Let me know!

Comment: This is having an error... To fetch is "something.field1, something.user_id" and it says I need to include something.field1 in groupy by clause... but I just want to group by the last inserted for the **user_id**, not field1... :S I'm still trying to solve it... sorry for the late reply!

Comment: Hey, you cant do that directly. I updated my answer. Try that and that should work. Let me know if not!

Comment: It sure did! Thank you so much for your help, you did everything you could at best! Amazing! Tyvm again :D

Comment: Awesome :) Glad to help you :)